# JavaFX: Force a binding to calculate eagerly

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding, javafx-8

Is there any way to write a binding (unidirectional one) such that the binding is calculated eagerly?

I am aware that using `ChangeListener` could easily solve that, but I would like to retain the ability to undo the binding via `Property.unbind()`.